# HTML Firefox table alignment issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, firefox

This code seems to run fine on every browser except for firefox. On firefox the first row of each table is properly aligned, but then the rest of the rows are way off to the right. This is my first website, so if there are any other proper coding practices im not following please let me know. The website is live and can be viewed at www.topclassfifa.com the coin pages are the ones having alignment problems with firefox.

```
<div class="center">
 <table id="XboxTable1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1000" 
    align="center" dir="ltr">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;" align="center" width="333" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Xbox50kIcon.png" /></td>
            <td style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;" align="center" width="334" colspan="0" rowspan="0"><asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Xbox100kIcon.png"/></td>
            <td style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;" align="center" width="333" colspan="0" rowspan="0"><asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Xbox250kIcon.png" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:medium"; width="333" align="center"colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <font color="#92C83E">£<%=Xbox50kPrice %></font></td>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:medium" width="334" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <font color="#92C83E">£<%=Xbox100kPrice %></font></td>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:medium" width="333" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <font color="#92C83E">£<%=Xbox250kPrice %></font></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 333px" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Quantity: " ForeColor="#92C83E"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown50kXbox" runat="server" Width="44px" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="Changed50kXbox" AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="#0168D4" 
                    ForeColor="#92C83E">
                    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 334px" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Quantity: " ForeColor="#92C83E"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown100kXbox" runat="server" Width="44px" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="Changed100kXbox" AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="#0168D4" 
                    ForeColor="#92C83E">
                    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 333px" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Quantity: " ForeColor="#92C83E"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown250kXbox" runat="server" Width="44px" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="Changed250kXbox" AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="#0168D4" 
                    ForeColor="#92C83E">
                    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>       
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 333px; font-weight: bold; font-size:large" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <font color="#92C83E">£<%=Xbox50kTotal %></font></td>
            <td style="width: 333px; font-weight: bold; font-size:large" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <font color="#92C83E">£<%=Xbox100kTotal %></font></td>
            <td style="width: 333px; font-weight: bold; font-size:large" align="center" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                <font color="#92C83E">£<%=Xbox250kTotal %></font></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `rowspan="0"` and `colspan="0"` attributes from your `<td>` tags.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really thought I had tried everything, but that took care of it.